# blocking vs nonblocking assignment

Tags: verilog, blocking

Can someone explain the intra-delay and delay statement?

It is simple logic, triggered by (a,b,c) and assign a&b&c to d.

```
module abcd(input a,b,c,output d);
    reg d;
    always @ (a, b, c)
        begin
        // d = #5 a & b & c;  //intra-delay
      #5    d = a & b & c;        //delay statement
        end
endmodule 

module tb;
    reg a,b,c;
    wire d;

    abcd a0(a,b,c,d);
    initial
        begin
            $monitor("time=%d, a=%b, b=%b, c=%b, d=%b",$time,a,b,c,d);
            a=0; b=0; c=0;
            #4 a=1; b=1; c=1;   //4
            #1 a=0; //5
            #1 a=1; //6
            #1 a=0; //7
            #1 a=1; //8
            #1 a=0; //9
            #1 a=1; //10
            #1 a=0; //11
            #1 a=1; //12
            #1 a=0; //13

            #100 $finish;
        end
endmodule
```

If intra-delay is used, the result is shown below

```
time=                   0, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=x
time=                   4, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=x
time=                   5, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                   6, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                   7, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                   8, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                   9, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  10, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  11, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  12, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  13, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  15, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1
```

If delay statement is used, the result is shown below.

```
time=                   0, a=0, b=0, c=0, d=x
time=                   4, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=x
time=                   5, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1
time=                   6, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1
time=                   7, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1
time=                   8, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1
time=                   9, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=1
time=                  10, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  11, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  12, a=1, b=1, c=1, d=0
time=                  13, a=0, b=1, c=1, d=0
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inter delay

Wait for the delay specified and then execute the command.

So:

```
#5    d = a & b & c;
```

will wait exactly **5** timesteps then execute and assign **a & b & c** to **d**.

### Intra-delay

Execute the command immediately and store the value. Assign the value after the delay specified.

So:

```
d = #5 a & b & c;
```

will store the result of **a & b & c** and assign it to **d** exactly **5** timesteps later.

---

As for explaining your outputs:

**Inter Delay**

The always block waits for 5 timesteps before executing a & b & c, and takes the value just before 5 timesteps when executing the command. Before 5 timesteps it is x because it is unassigned. At 5 timesteps it performs a&b&c with a=1, b=1, c=1 (the value at 4 timesteps) and comes out with d=1.

d will stay at this value until 5 further timesteps where it will perform a&b&c with the value at 9 timesteps. This will result in d=0. d will stay at 0 for 5 further timesteps.

This cycle repeats until you tell it to $finish.

**Intra Delay**

Before 5 timesteps nothing is assigned, so the output is x.

At **time=0** a & b & c with a=0,b=0,c=0 causing d=0 is executed and will be assigned at time=5.

At **time=5** a & b & c is executed with a=0,b=1,c=1 causing d=0. This will be assigned at time=10.

At **time=10** a & b & c is executed with a=1,b=1,c=1 causing d=1. This will be assigned at time=15.